# How to use dynamic variable in regExp using javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex, bootstrapvalidator

I know this question already has an answer. I have read this [answer][1]. But it doesn't work for me. Since I am new to regEx and js, I didn't understand why they use these kinds of code like below for passing parameter.

```
var replace = "regex";
var re = new RegExp(replace,"g");
```

I have attached my code which I wrote in JSP. I used bootstrap validator. Please find it below

```
/* Get the domain name from the controller */ 

var domainName = ${domainName}

                  /*Validation part*/  
         email: {
                    trigger: 'blur',
                    validators: {
                        notEmpty: {
                            message: 'The email address is required'
                        },
                        regexp: {
                            regexp : /"^([\w-\.]+)@" + domainName/,
                            message: 'The domain name is wrong and your domain name is: ' + domainName
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Here I have written regexp as **/"^([\w-.]+)@" + domainName/**. In message I have written the variable name as **domainName**. So the message has been shown in the GUI. I need to know how to pass the variable (domainName) to regEx. Please explain how to do that?

**EDIT 1:**
If I hardcode regEx like this, it works. But hardcoding is not great idea.

```
           regexp : /^([\w-\.]+)@(example.com|example1.com|uk.co|gmail.com)$/,
```

**ANSWER:**
I solved this issue. 
Once I got the domain name, I have divided the regex and domain name in separate variables and concatenated them in variable(pattern).

```
    var domainName = ${domainName}

        const pattern1 = String.raw`([\w-\.]+)`;
        const pattern2 = (domainName);
        const pattern = new RegExp("^" + pattern1 + "@" + pattern2 + "$");
```

I have mentioned the variable "pattern" in validation part and its worked successfully.

```
                email: {
                    trigger: 'blur',
                    validators: {
                        notEmpty: {
                            message: 'The email address is required and cannot be empty'
                        },
                        regexp: {
                            regexp : pattern,
                            message: 'The domain name is wrong and your domain name is: ' + domainName

                        }

                    }
                },

  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/494035/how-do-you-use-a-variable-in-a-regular-expression
```

Comment: Please show us this code as it is rendered in the browser - its not much fun trying to debug in two different languages simultaneously!

Comment: @Mike Brokington The code I attached is taken from the corresponding JSP page only. I got domainName from the controller using EL as I mentioned in the first line of code.

Comment: @Toto read my question properly

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Regex contractor that accepts string.

```js
const regex = new RegExp('"^([\w-.]+)@"' + domainName);
```

**EDIT**

Change this line:

```
regexp : /"^([\w-\.]+)@" + domainName/,
```

to:

```
regexp : new RegExp('"^([\w-.]+)@"' + domainName),
```

Comment: Can you tell me where should I write this? I am completely new to the front end. I have written like this ```var domainName = ${domainName},const regex = new RegExp('"^([\w-.]+)@"' + domainName);``` and used the regex like /regex/ above the message line

Comment: updated my answer.

Comment: It is not worked

Comment: OK, and what is the error? output?

Comment: It accepts all domain names. Actually the form opens in iframe

Comment: I have edited the question

Answer (score 0):

You can try this 
JavaScript automatically adds "/" at the end and the beginning of the expression. So you can ignore them.

```
 var expression = "^([\w-\.]+)@ + domainName" ;
```

Comment: this is **not** a javascript regex but a regular **string**

Comment: @Srimoyee Sen It won't work